# Javascript em pagina JSF - PrimeFace

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Codigo HTML - JAVASCRIPT Ele ler um arquivo txt do computador e coloca seu valor em um input html

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<input type="text" required name="txtstart" style="width:150px" value="">

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var saida = "";
    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          saida+=e.target.result;
          document.querySelector("[name='txtstart']").value = saida;
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Quero colocar essa mesma logica no primeface, mas não consigo fazer com que o arquivo selecionado entre em um **p:inputTextarea** tentei fazer igual no HTML sem as tag **p:** mas mesmo assim o javascript não é executado.

Resumindo, preciso ler um arquivo do computador e colocar seu valor dentro do componente abaixo:

```
<p:inputTextarea value="#{polylinesView.texto}" rows="7" cols="20"
                                     scrollHeight="10" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer o upload de arquivos utilizando primefaces geralmente utiliza-se o componente file upload. Segue exemplo de como ele poderia ser escrito:

```
<h:form>
<p:fileUpload value="#{beanController.arquivoAula}" sizeLimit="20971520" invalidSizeMessage="Somente são aceitos arquivos de até 20MB"
                    label="Selecionar arquivo" cancelLabel="Cancelar" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt)$/" 
                    invalidFileMessage="Somente são aceitos arquivos dos tipos: txt " 
                    fileUploadListener="#{beanController.handleFileUpload}" process="@form" update="@form" />

                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{cursoController.campoTextArea}">

                    </p:inputTextarea>
</h:form>
```

O método `handleFileUpload` deve estar implementado no seu managedbean semelhante ao apresentado a seguir:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){
    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();

    byte[] contents = event.getFile().getContents();
    String dados = new String(contents);
    this.campoTextArea = dados;
}
```

Uma vez que foi feito o upload do arquivo os dados serão lidos e adicionados na String `campoTextArea` que está associada ao textarea no formulário.

Segue link da documentação do fileupload:[link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml)